# How to conditionally display certain information in emails on Outlook.com?

Tags: email, outlook, conditional-statements

I've been banging my head (as expected with email) trying to make a rather complicated responsive email function correctly in every mail client Litmus.com offers for testing.

I've pretty much reached a solution, which involves scattering a few conditionals for `(gte mso 9)`, `(IE)` and `!mso` et al. The problem is Outlook.com ignores them.

My final problem is that the repeatable items that compose the main part of the email don't display well in Outlook.com. I've tried adding a class to the item designed specifically for Outlook.com, setting that to `display: none` and then prepending ecx to the class name and forcing `display: block` on that. Unfortunately that seems to affect Gmail.com, too.

Does anyone know of a reliable way I can handle this situation? I can't see any way I can make it work properly with Outlook.com's whacky rendering without some form of conditionals.

The last-ditch solution I can think of is to display a message linking to an image or HTML version of the email.. but it's slightly more complex since the email is generated dynamically, on a per-user, per-time basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only thought I have to help would be to use the 'mso-hide:all' css.  Mind you in nested tables, you will need to use on each section to make sure it is not rendered.

e.g. `<table style="mso-hide:all;">`

I have not tested this in Outlook.com, but thought maybe it might help...